# How to add class in li element (for page where I am) in menu for drupal 8

Tags: routes, 8

I would like to add class in li element in menu for drupal 8 for page where I am. For example if i am on page Start, that li have active class. Or If I am on Join page that li element for join have active class.

```
<ul class="">
<li class="active"><a href="#" >START</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#" >About</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#" >join</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, How to ask if li is active or no?

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item=SOMETHING %}
    <li class="active">
      <a  href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li >
      <a  href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: try first with css only `li a:active  { color:red; text-decoration:underline; }`

Comment: Soryy I didnt ask question good. :( I would like to add class=active for page where i am.

Comment: I actually got that, but try my css code to see if it works. (it might auto detect the page you are on and underline the Menu `li` accordingly)

Comment: Is work but when you click on menu item and muve him http://prntscr.com/a4tpmy its seem that auto detection dont work.

Comment: why would anyone do that? you really think your users will do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add active class to `<li>` need to add the following code in your `.theme` file and `menu.html.twig`

In **.theme** file add this

```
function themename_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'menu__main') { // If it is not working replace "main__menu" with "menu"

    // Get the current path.
    $current_path = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
    $items = $variables['items'];
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
      // If path is current_path, set active to li.
      if ($item['url']->toString() == $current_path) {
      // Add active link.
      $variables['items'][$key]['attributes']['class'] = 'active';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In menu.html.twig replace your `<li>` with below line.

replace this line

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
```

by

```
<li {{ item.attributes }} ><a  href="{{ item.url }}"  {{ item.attributes }} > {{ item.title }}</a></li>
```

Comment: If doing this you also need to add the current URL to the cache context for the menu, otherwise when caching is enabled the preprocess hook won't actually run for each page. So, e.g. add to the code above:

`$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.path';`

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if you programmatically detect the page and apply the class on that condition.You can follow the following steps.

- Detect the current page (  CODE : For Drupal 7) .

  ```
   <php
    $path = current_path();
    $path_alias = drupal_lookup_path('alias',$path);
   ?>
  ```
- Add the if condition matching your page name with that of current page

  ```
  if($path_alias == "current-page") { print  "active"; }
  ```

This may solve your issue