# Considering two solutions for adding classes to a menu

Tags: 8, theming

Ive subthemed the main bootstrap theme, and i just want to add classes to my main menu and menu items, so my two solutions would be to:

1.copy menu--main.html.twig  into my templates folder, that way overrideing the original, and then just delete all of that attributes/class logic they've added and add my own classes.

This was my initial idea, but then i looked at their attributes logic:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu', 'nav', 'navbar-nav') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('dropdown-menu') }}>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {% if menu_level == 0 and item.is_expanded %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('expanded', 'dropdown') }}>
        <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      {% else %}
        <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if item.bel{#
        {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav', 'navbar-nav'), menu_level + 1) }}
      {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I Thouth that there had to be a good reason why they have it, so i was thinking about doing the second solution:

2. preprocess function for the template and add the attributes there. But the logic would be something like:

   ```
       function itkweb_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
            if($variables['menu_name'] = "main") {
                $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'someclass';
              }
        }
   ```

So basically the question is why would i keep the attribute logic, or why would i just delete it?

Another question is, what is the name of the preprocess function, if i wanted to target the menu--main.html.twig specifically? the menu would be 
_preprocess_menu    so ive tried to mix in main, but i can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: See my question.  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191845/how-to-add-class-in-li-element-for-page-where-i-am-in-menu-for-drupal-8

Comment: Yeah okay, i see the usefulness of that, im looking a bit more into twig right now, to figuire out what exactly that bootstrap menu template does, and then i think il combine it with your solution. Thanks ! :)